# python redirect from container to container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

Im using docker-compose version 1.25.0 , i have 2 containers

api - with python script and flask

apach - some gui

I want when i get a curl request to api `/test` it will redirect to apach container gui internaly,
This is the python code in api container:

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return redirect('apach:4822/#/myapp', code=302)
```

If i use this code to my host externaly `return redirect('10.X.X.X:4822/#/myapp', code=302)` it works but i want the redirect to be internally between the containers, the redirect is not working this way.

I tried to do curl to `apach:4822/#/myapp` from api container and i do see it goes through
to the apach container, but with my python code it doesnt and i get the code 302 and page does not exists.

How can i make it work ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `redirect('apach:4822/#/myapp', code=302)` is not working because the name `apach` is resolvable only inside the docker network set up by docker-compose.

Flask is sending the HTTP 302 code with [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) header set to `apach:4822/#/myapp` to your browser. From the machine where your browser is running, `apach` can't be resolved. So you need to use an externally resolvable IP only.

Since you have multiple services that you want to expose to external world, you should look at setting up a reverse proxy server like [nginx](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx). You can run `nginx` as a container itself. You could expose your services on different routes using nginx. For example, your `api` service can be exposed at `/api/` path and your `apach` container can be exposed at `/myapp` path. Users would connect to the nginx server and nginx would route to the request to appropriate backend service depending on the requested URL. When users connect to `/api/test`, you could redirect to `/myapp` with `redirect('/myapp', code=302)`. nginx would then route the request to `apach` service.

Comment: There isnt a way to redirect between containers ? i get why it doesnt work but i do need a way to make it work.

Comment: Instead of redirect, maybe you can make the request from your api container to apach container and forward the response?

Comment: There isnt any response, its supposed to show the person who sent through the broser the  /test , to the apach container gui.

Comment: Well, there is no way for a redirect to work if the location is not accessible. What you can do is setup a reverse proxy server like nginx and put your services behind the proxy on different paths. Users would connect to your services via the reverse proxy server. Then you could just do `redirect('/myapp', code=302)` in your flask app and reverse proxy would take care of serving the request from your `apach` container.

Comment: Hey thank you i did nginx container as a reversed proxy and it works